# Animation loop - css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** I've created simple infinite animation using css, but there are a simple problem that I need the animation is loop for ever smoothly.

```css
.rotate{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:50px auto;
    background-color:#00e95a;
    animation-name:rotate;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
        -o-transform: rotate(0);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
        transform: rotate(0);
    }

    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="rotate">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `animation-timing-function: linear;`.

**Note**: The problem was caused by the default timing state, which is **ease**.

```css
.rotate {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: #00e95a;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: Aww...beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

As @Kind user has mentioned you should hard reset `animation-timing-function` to `linear`, because the *intial value* of `animation-timing-function` is `ease`.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function